# One hour difference in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime.datetime property var.
I would like to know if it is less than one hour of the current time.
Something like

```
var.hour<datetime.datetime.today().hour - 1
```

Problem with the above syntax is that

```
datetime.datetime.today().hour
```

returns a number such as "10" and it is not really a date comparation but more of a numbers comparation.

What is the correct syntax?

Thanks!

Joel

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use `datetime.timedelta`.

```
var < datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: That should be
var < datetime.datetime.today() - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
without the var.HOUR, right?:)

Comment: that's correct.  datetime.hour is an int and not something that can be compared with datetime objects

Comment: Since you only need to get the difference in hours, this one is good enough. dateutil.relativedelta gives you more: years, months etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [dateutil.relativedelta](http://labix.org/python-dateutil)

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta

now = datetime.now()
other_time = now + timedelta(hours=8)
diff = relativedelta(other_time, now)
print diff.hours # 8
```